# Visual Studio 2017 Connection String Unable to Connect To Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, webforms

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 Community.  I am beginning a new ASP.net WebForms C# project, but I'm having an issue with my connection string.  Here's what I have done thus far:
Created a WebForms application with individual user accounts
Changed the DefaultConnection in the web.config file to

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=s13.example.com;Initial Catalog=DB_9;User ID=DB_9_user;Password=myPwd;Integrated Security=False;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Then I add a SqlDataSource and attempt to use the DefaultConnection, but I get the following error:

> Database schema could not be retrieved for this connection.  Please
>   make sure the connection settings are correct and that the database is
>   online.
>   Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>   Failed to connect to server (local).
>   Login failed for user 'DB_9_user'.

Next, I verified that the server, username and password were correct.  I used the same credentials in Sql Server Management Studio 2012 to connect to the database successfully.  So next I pulled-up my old computer with Visual Studio 2013 Professional and recreated the project on there.  There were no issues at all changing the connection string and using it in a SqlDataSource control.  Is there something different about the VS 2017 Community Edition that is blocking my ability to connect to the Database?

Answer (score 2):

Here was my workaround for this problem.  In Visual Studio, Tools->Connect to Database.  Use the same credentials and server name as your connection string.  Then when you go to create your new Datasource, select SQL Database as the Data Source Type.  When you Choose Your Data Connection, the connection you created earlier should be available to select from instead of using the Connection String. This will create a new Connection String and will be added to your web.config file.  This should look exactly like your previous connection string.  You can replace the old connection string with this one if you choose to mind you update anything using the old connection string.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete solution, but I noticed a couple things that may help:

1. > Failed to connect to server (local)

   That's not the server mentioned in the connection string. This means it's looking for a database server on your local workstation. Are you sure it's using the right object, or the right string?
2. > s13.example.com

   That's kind of scary, in that it looks like a public address. Are you trying to connect directly to the production host over the internet? That's not good. Typically, the database server is not directly accessible to the outside world. The web server will sit in a DMZ, where outside users can hit the web server, and the web server can hit the DB server on the inside, but outside users can't get directly to the DB server. For very small sites, they might be the machine, but those rules should still be enforced by the firewall: no public access to the database. For development, you work against a private copy of the database, rather than something hosted online.

Comment: <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=testdb;uid=sa;pwd=jsid6873;" />.  
Failed to retrieve data for this request.
Failed to connect to server (local).
Login failed for user 'testdb'.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your connection string:

```
Persist Security Info=True;
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

use `Persist Security Info=True;` in your connection string.
If you try to connect using server explorer or object explorer from vs IDE then Check the "Save my password" checkbox when you add new database connection.